# Defining ForeignKeys with Code First

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to define a relationship between 2 tables with the `ForeignKeyAttribute`.
I came a cross a few sites that described an interesting method of doing this with the `ForeignKeyAttribute`.

Here are the two code samples:

The first one:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    // Some other properties

    [ForeignKey("OrderID")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    // Some other properties

    [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

The second one:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Order")]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    // Some other properties

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    // Some other properties

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

In the first code sample, the `ForeignKeyAttribute` is placed on the `public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }`.

And in the second code sample on the `public int CustomerID { get; set; }` (Order- and CustomerID).

My question is, how do I know which method to use in which situation?

I know this could be done too using `Fluent API`, but that's irrelevant at the moment for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, just want to say that you do not need to place the `ForeignKey` attribute on any property. Simply doing the following should be enough:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //EF will create the relationship since the property is named class+id
    //the following is not necessary, is just good practice
    //if this is omitted EF will create a Order_Id on its own
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    // Some other properties

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{    
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // no need to include the id property
    // Some other properties

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Having said that, the answer is that the `ForeignKey` construct takes in a string parameter. If you place it on the foreign key property it should have the name of the navigation property, if you place it on the navigation property it should have the name of the foreign key. Where you place it is completely up to you, as long as you keep in mind what `string` value to use.

Comment: Hi, about your last line, other than that, there are no difference which method is used in any way?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make a difference where you place the `ForeignKey`